# Resuming Download after WiFi failure while the app is in background using NSURLSession?

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios7, nsurlsession, completionhandler

I have seen many posts discussing about WiFi loss in the background the background,But still can't find any workarounds.I'm using NSURLSession to download a set of files in background.The issue is when WiFi goes off the downloads are cancelled.Is there any way to restart the download while the app is still in the background.Im aware of the background daemon and delegates regarding NSURLSession but still could'nt find a work around.Please help?

Is there any way to understand that the Background daemon is currently downloading files or is idle? It seems that the downloads getting paused while the app is background for 2-3 Hours?

Comment: have you tried to listen for notifications from Reachability class?

Comment: Im not able to listen to Reachability notification while app is in background.

Comment: @Siriss At that time i was not able to solve this issue.But in WWDC 14 Videos says OS will handle the wifi failures.